# SQL how to Count

Tags: sql

I have a database phone and i would like to track on the dates where how many phone call or how many SMS being for a period of 1 week for example

```
DATABASE:phone

type | date/time

calls           | 04/01/14 0800hrs

sms            | 04/01/14 0850hrs

sms            | 04/01/14 0900hrs

calls           | 04/01/14 1230hrs

sms            | 04/01/14 1250hrs

calls           | 04/01/14 1300hrs

sms            | 08/01/14 1301hrs

calls          | 08/01/14 1330hrs
```

how should i create a table and use count?which will show

```
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_

-no. of calls  || no. of sms-

-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_

-4             || 4         -

-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_
```

I foget to add in. lets say i got user 1, 2 and 3. 
I want to search user 1 made how many phone calls and how many sms, user 2 made how many phone calls and how many sms and so on. how should i write it?

Answer (score 0):

If you execute query on SQL Server, the follow SQL should work:

```
SELECT [type], COUNT([type]) FROM your_table
WHERE DATEPART(wk, your_table.[datetime]) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(yy, your_table.[datetime]) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())
GROUP BY [type]
```

**Update**: You didn't tell about user field earlier. However, you can modify its GROUP clause to get the new expected result as follows:

```
SELECT [user_name], [type], COUNT([type]) FROM your_table
WHERE DATEPART(wk, your_table.[datetime]) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
AND DATEPART(yy, your_table.[datetime]) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())
GROUP BY [type], [user_name]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Btw if i had a search function like user 1, 2, 3. and i only wan to see like user 1 make how many sms or phone calls, user 2 made how many sms or phone calls, how should i input to check?

Comment: You didn't tell about user field earlier. However, you can modify its GROUP clause to get the new expected result: GROUP BY [type], [user_name]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) FROM phone where [date/time] between x and y group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'calls' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS 'no_of_calls',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'sms' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS 'no_of_SMS'
FROM Table1
```

Or:

```
SELECT Distinct Type,Count(Type) AS CountOf From Table1 Group By Type
```